# javascript foreach onclick

Tags: javascript, foreach, onclick

```
<? foreach($words as $word): ?>
<li>
    <button onClick="reply_click()">Show</button>
    <h4><?php echo $word['Word']['en_words'] ?></h4>
</li>
<? endforeach; ?>
<script>
function reply_click() {
    $("h4").toggle("slow");
}
</script>
```

When I click 'button' - shows all, in every foreach, but must show in only one. Where I must used 'this' that this script work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another variant pass *this* to function

```
<button onclick="reply_click(this)">Show</button>

<script>

function reply_click(btn) {
    $(btn).next("h4").toggle("slow");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use inline handlers.

Better Approach:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'button', function() {
    $(this).next('h4').show();
});
```

Comment: _this_ in inline handler refers to _window_

Comment: If it was in an inline handler it would refer to an element, but it is in a function that is being called as a global and that is why it is `window`.

Comment: I have no idea why you guys are talking about this underneath his answer. He is right, this is the better approach

Comment: @Tushar, I know, I was the first one to ^1, Im just saying, they are talking about an irrelevant subject regarding your answer :)

Comment: @AmmarCSE, before editing in answer used _this_ that refers to global object, so all comment was relevant

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<li>
    <button onClick="reply_click(this.nextElementSibling)">Show</button>
    <h4><?php echo $word['Word']['en_words'] ?></h4>
</li>

function reply_click(el) {
    $(el).toggle("slow");
}
```

> The **NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling** read-only property
>   returns the element **immediately** following the specified one in its
>   parent's children list, or null if the specified element is the last
>   one in the list.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)

Thank you @Grundy

Comment: possibly better [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) instead [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, depending on the situation you can select the heading inside the click handler function like one of the solutions below;

```
$(this).next("h4");

$(this).closest("h4");

$(this).siblings("h4");
```

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: so, possibly you provide sampe for case in OP?

Answer (score 0):

Use **next()** - https://api.jquery.com/next/

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves
>   the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

```
<button onClick="reply_click(this)">Show</button>

<script>
function reply_click(e) {
    $(e).next("h4").toggle("slow");
}
</script>
```

If you want to avoid the inline click handler, you can add a class to your button and change the script to this.

```
<button class="toggleChild">Show</button>
<script>
$(".toggleChild").on("click", function(){
    $(this).next("h4").toggle("slow");
});
</script>
```